# What gives Maglev trains forward horizontal motion?

Tags: magnetic-fields, levitation

Maglev trains have superconductors which are immune to magnetic field lines with low enough temperature. Due to this property, they levitate on magnetic rails as magnetic field lines are bended below them to create magnetic river.

But, isn't the lift force vertical here? There are sideway magnetic repulsors to keep the train on track but this can also not give the train forward motion. What gives Maglev trains forward horizontal motion?

At railway stations, trains can be pushed or stopped gently with magnetic force (and, there's no wheel friction), but trains don't necessarily run in Vacuum. I have listened that most of energy is wasted in overcoming air drag rather than lifting. What consumes this energy?

Comment: Have you checked  the wiki article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mag-lev_train

Comment: This has an explanation for propulsion in the second frame http://science.howstuffworks.com/transport/engines-equipment/maglev-train.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many systems for maglev trains. For the system of my question, I found that forward horizontal motion can be given by [Linear Induction Motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_induction_motor).